# An error when opening multiple webdrivers in multi-thread processing in python

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium

I am using python to do web scraping. I am trying to use multi-threading to speed up the scraping. And, I will use selenium. So, in each thread, I open one webdriver. When I open 4 threads, the program goes well. However, when I try to open 5 threads or more than 5 threads, the program returns an error as follows:

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\users\\apogne\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpqzhfxq.webdriver.xpi\\platform\\WINNT_x86-msvc\\components\\webdriver-firefox-latest.dll'
```

The program can be simplified as follows and the same error still occurs.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from threading import Thread

def f():    
    driver=webdriver.Firefox()    
    driver.close()

thread_list=[]

for i in range(5):
    t=Thread(target=f)    
    t.start()    
    thread_list.append(t)

for t in thread_list:    
    t.join()
```

The full trace of the error is as follows.

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\pinterest\user_info_multiThread.py", line 21, in gettingUserInfo
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.profile.add_extension()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 92, in add_extension
    self._install_extension(extension)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 285, in _install_extension
    shutil.rmtree(tmpdir)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\users\\apogne\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpadxbvj.webdriver.xpi\\platform\\WINNT_x86-msvc\\components\\webdriver-firefox-previous.dll'

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\pinterest\user_info_multiThread.py", line 21, in gettingUserInfo
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 121, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: u'c is null' ; Stacktrace: 
    at nsCommandProcessor.prototype.newSession (file:///c:/users/apogne/appdata/local/temp/tmpr0rxvj/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11751:61)
    at nsCommandProcessor.prototype.execute (file:///c:/users/apogne/appdata/local/temp/tmpr0rxvj/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11646:7)
    at Dispatcher.executeAs/< (file:///c:/users/apogne/appdata/local/temp/tmpr0rxvj/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:8430:5)
    at Resource.prototype.handle (file:///c:/users/apogne/appdata/local/temp/tmpr0rxvj/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:8577:219)
    at Dispatcher.prototype.dispatch (file:///c:/users/apogne/appdata/local/temp/tmpr0rxvj/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:8524:36)
    at WebDriverServer/<.handle (file:///c:/users/apogne/appdata/local/temp/tmpr0rxvj/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:11466:5)
    at createHandlerFunc/< (file:///c:/users/apogne/appdata/local/temp/tmpr0rxvj/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1935:41)
    at ServerHandler.prototype.handleResponse (file:///c:/users/apogne/appdata/local/temp/tmpr0rxvj/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:2261:15)
    at Connection.prototype.process (file:///c:/users/apogne/appdata/local/temp/tmpr0rxvj/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1168:5)
    at RequestReader.prototype._handleResponse (file:///c:/users/apogne/appdata/local/temp/tmpr0rxvj/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1616:5)
    at RequestReader.prototype._processBody (file:///c:/users/apogne/appdata/local/temp/tmpr0rxvj/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1464:9)
    at RequestReader.prototype.onInputStreamReady (file:///c:/users/apogne/appdata/local/temp/tmpr0rxvj/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1333:9) 

Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\pinterest\user_info_multiThread.py", line 24, in gettingUserInfo
    driver.get("http://www.pinterest.com")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 185, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 171, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 349, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 380, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1067, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 373, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
BadStatusLine: ''

Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\pinterest\user_info_multiThread.py", line 24, in gettingUserInfo
    driver.get("http://www.pinterest.com")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 185, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 171, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 349, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 380, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1067, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 373, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
BadStatusLine: ''

Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\pinterest\user_info_multiThread.py", line 24, in gettingUserInfo
    driver.get("http://www.pinterest.com")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 185, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 171, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 349, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 380, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1067, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 373, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
BadStatusLine: ''
```

Does anyone know why this error occurs and how can I fix it?

Comment: Recommend phrasing your question in the form of a question.

Comment: I don't think webdriver is thread-safe.

Comment: Someone suggests me to use multiprocessing instead of threading. However, when I run the code in the Idle, the multiprocessing is not working at all. It does not go into the function and nothing in the function is executed. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a full stack trace? Also, what version of selenium are you using?

Comment: I have just added the full trace. I forget the version of the selenium... How can I see it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a lock for

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
```

so that only one thread at a time is bootstrapping the driver

edit:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from threading import Thread, Lock

def f():    
    #thread will either acquire lock or wait for it to be released by other thread
    with my_lock:
        #init this driver
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()    

    #do your other stuff

    driver.close()

thread_list=[]
my_lock = Lock()

for _ in xrange(5):
    t = Thread( target=f )    
    t.start()    
    thread_list.append( t )

for t in thread_list:    
    t.join()
```

Comment: How to do that? If so, how can multithreading work? Multithreading is just aimed at using multiple drivers simultaneously.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects - The point is to make it so that only one thread instantiates a webdriver instance at a time, then the threading will continue normally

Comment: Thank you. But then what is the advantage of using multithread? I try your code. Each time, only one browser is open. So, the speed of the data crawling will be the same as a single thread program.

Comment: I assume that your intended program is doing more than just opening and closing a driver... in this case the point is that after you have created your drivers (one at a time) they can then continue simultaneously -- if you are new to threading I suggest you use multiprocessing because it is more friendly to newbies (but you will still need the lock)